# Remove values found in both arrays

Tags: php

What I'm looking to do is compare two arrays and remove values that are found in both arrays.

such that:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => 12356
    [1] => 34567
    [2] => 67890
)

Array2
(
    [0] => 12356
    [1] => 66666
    [2] => 22222
)
```

And the result that I need is

```
Array3
    (
        [0] => 12356
    )
```

Wondering if there's a quick way to do this before I build some function to handle it.

Comment: it seems that you want values that are found in both arrays, rather than you want to remove values that are found in both arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```